# Issue with Flutter pub get: showing old Version even I my terminal shows the newest one

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am facing an issue while running "pub get" for my Flutter project.
The error message is saying that my Dart SDK version is 2.17.1, and that my project requires a version greater than or equal to 2.19.6 and less than 3.0.0. However, I have already installed the latest Dart SDK version (3.0.5).

The Error started since I downgraded my Flutter to add a widget which require a old version...

[Version actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMc74.png)

[what after pub get getting recconized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgRMj.png)
Despite having the latest Dart SDK version, I still receive the error message stating that the current version is 2.17.1. This seems to be a configuration issue or conflict between different versions.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this problem and successfully run "pub get" for my Flutter project with the correct Dart SDK version.

Thank youuu.

I have tried updating Flutter using "flutter upgrade," but the issue persists. I have also checked my Dart SDK version using "dart --version," and it confirms that I have the correct version installed.

(I also tried to set the yaml to 2.19.6 to 3.0.5)